# SFINAE not working to conditionally compile member function template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-c++, sfinae

I'm trying you use `std::enable_if` to conditionally choose only one out of two member function template using SFINAE with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct C {
    template<typename Q = T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, int>::value>::type>
    int foo() {
        return 1;
    }

    template<typename Q = T, typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Q, int>::value>::type>
    int foo() {
        return 0;
    }

};

int main() {
    std::cout << C<int>().foo() << std::endl;  //error member function foo already defined
}
```

but for some reason, visual c++ keeps giving me a compiler error that `foo` is already defined. Even though, it is clear that, depending on the class' template argument, only one function is well-formed. So SFINAE should remove the second one from consideration.

Any idea why this does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
template<typename T>
struct C {
    template<typename Q = T,
             typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Q, int>::value, bool>::type = true>
    int foo() { // .............................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return 1;
    }

    template<typename Q = T, 
             typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Q, int>::value, bool>::type = true>
    int foo() { // ..............................................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return 0;
    }

};
```

the point is that in your code SFINAE will enable/disable default values for template type parameter; but default values do not participate in overload resolution, so, in your case, you have two functions

```
template<typename, typename = void>
int foo() {
    return 1;
}

template<typename, typename>
int foo() {
    return 0;
}
```

with the same signature; so the compiler can't choose between the two and will give an error.

The code I proposed is different because in case the test of `std::enable_if` is false, you don't have the type (the element on the left of the `=`), not the value. Something as

```
// ................VVVVVV   what is = true ?
template<typename, = true>
int foo() {
    return 1;
}
```

that is a true "substitution failure" that disable the method.

Comment: @GamefanA - yes... I'm trying to improve the answer but ins't easy (for me) to explain

Comment: @GamefanA - answer improved; hope this is more clear.